# How do I align this CSS correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I'm trying to add padding to a profile image and align it as shown below in my bootstrap page.

**Here's how it looks as of current:**

[image]

**And here's how I want it to look:**

[image]

(notice that the username is on top with the profile image and the comment text is below but aligned alongside with the profile image)

Here's the HTML: (I'm kind of new with Bootstrap)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="~/Images/avatar.png" class="profile-picture" />
            <label>Username - 1 month ago</label>
            <p>
                This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my CSS that adds a bit of padding to the profile image:

```
.profile-picture
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: So are you looking for the image to be modified or the `<p>` tag?

Comment: this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/yJUH4/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Bootstrap3 documentation, use of the media class should work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 media">
        <img src="~/Images/avatar.png" class="media-object profile-picture" />

        <div class="media-body>
            <label class="media-heading">Username - 1 month ago</label>
            This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More documentation on this here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

Comment: I ended up using this - thanks a lot.
Also thanks to everyone else who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider giving some css property to the p tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/hXaRG/2/`">Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.profile-picture{float:left;margin-right:5px;}
.row p {margin-top:0;margin-left:52px;}
.row{width:500px;background:gray;}
```

this is the result final :

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3q2DOPnNwNhM29SYXhEMXhlc3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It really doesn't help me achieve what I'm asking.

Comment: sorry! answer Updated @JordanAxe I tested this code and it's work :)

Comment: The text is not aligned along with the profile picture. As soon as the text is longer than the picture it starts filling up directly below the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have to float the image and the content to achieve the desired result. You have to modify a bit the html code like this :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="~/Images/avatar.png" class="profile-picture" />
                <div class="comment">
                    <label>Username - 1 month ago</label>
                    <p>
                    This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. This is the text of the comment. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the css

```
.profile-picture, .comment{float:left;}
.comment label {display: block;}
```

I haven't put the margin's / padding's that you want.

Comment: But now the text is below the image - I need it to be beside the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.row {
    position:relative;
    background: #999;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.col-md-12 {
    padding-left:80px;  
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3hCez/)**

(Note the background color on .row is only for visualization purposes)